# Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types

The following code is: 1. Reading a folder. 2. Merging and auto-cropping images. 3. Saving the final images into png files.

```
const filenames = fs.readdirSync('./in').map(filename => {
  return path.parse(filename).name
})

const finalImages = filenames.forEach(async filename => {
  const bottomImage = await jimp.read(`./in/${filename}.png`)
  const topImage = await jimp.read('./dots.png')
  const file = bottomImage
    .composite(topImage, 0, 0)
    .autocrop(false)
  return {
    filename,
    file
  }
})

finalImages.forEach((finalImage: any) => {
  finalImage.file.write(`./out/${finalImage.filename}.png`)
})
```

I'm getting this typescript error:

[image]

> Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'void'.

What could be the reason, and how to fix it?

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything, you'll need to use `map` instead with `await Promise.all`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#return_value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you wanted to use is `map` instead of `forEach`.
`map` iterates over an array and returns a new one, while `forEach` simply iterates without returning anything.

This is why TS compiler infers that type of `finalImages` is `void`.